# Trouble in executing Amelia Package in R using command line

Tags: r, bash, imputation

I'm using Amelia package to imput my dataset, when I'm using R console I can run my R script without any issue and I get the result, but when I try to execute it trough command line (in mac) it does not work properly. Here is what  happens:

```
username$ Rscript RScript.r
Loading required package: foreign
## 
## Amelia II: Multiple Imputation
## (Version 1.6.4, built: 2012-12-17)
## Copyright (C) 2005-2016 James Honaker, Gary King and Matthew Blackwell
## Refer to http://gking.harvard.edu/amelia/ for more information
##
```

and then it halts whithout proceeding further. I'm new to R and I just want to run the R script that I have from my python code in order to impute my dataset that's why I need this to be run using command line.

Comment: Aer your script expecting to read from a file? Might be r waiting for input on standard input?

Comment: Depending on your data imputation can take some time and I've even occasionally had a Markov Chain that apparently didn't converge.

Comment: @andlrc yes actually it does but the file is in the same folder. Should I do anything in addition for reading from file? Here is the R script :
    `code' library(Amelia)
    require(foreign)
    idvars = c( 'Text', 'photo' )
    mydata = read.csv("file.csv")

    a.out = amelia( mydata, idvars = idvars )
  
   write.amelia( a.out, file.stem = 'impData' )

Comment: @MahShid Not when you explicit set the file to be read like that.

Comment: Update: I tried running my script in windows , the same thing happens. I think the problem relates with Amelia package in R as I could run other R scripts via command-line which use common R packages but no luck with Amelia yet.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for anyone to be able to help you.